# Emf of a rod sliding on two conducting rails

Tags: homework-and-exercises, voltage

The following is the question.
[image]

Actually, I do not know how to find the answer. I have tried to find out the solution or hints from the lecture note given to me but it is quite difficult to understand. The following is what I have tried.

[image]

Please give me some hints. Thank a lot.

(Ans : 0.14V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steps:

1. emf= change in magnetic flux/ time
2. Therefore, emf=(BA)/time
3. Magnetic field strength B is constant. So, we just have to find change in area by time
4. The length of AC will increase by 0.6m per second. As six second passed, AC=0.6*6. The BC can be calculated, BC= ACtan19
5. At the beginning, area is zero. After 6 seconds, area=0.5AC*BC. Thus, change is area, area=0.5AC*BC-0
6. So, AVERAGE EMF can be calculated:
   EMF= rate of change in magnetic flux=0.38*(change in area within six seconds)/6